# Email validation swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, email-validation

how do I restrict users enter email address into the textfield.
the problem is, my alert not shown, just signup without check the email field if valid or not

```
if ( username.isEmpty || email.isEmpty || password.isEmpty || phonenumper.isEmpty) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sign Up Failed!", message:"Please enter your data for Signup", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK ", style: .Default) { _ in })
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
}

else {
    if (isValidEmail(UserEmailTextFiled.text!)) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Inviled Email", message:"Please enter your Email", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK ", style: .Default) { _ in })
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}

    }else{
    //code

    }
func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
        let range = testStr.rangeOfString(emailRegEx, options:.RegularExpressionSearch)
        let result = range != nil ? true : false
        return result
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you to update isValidEmail to take an optional String as param, instead of String, and return false if its nil. It may avoid crash ( you always unwraps the optional value without check )

Comment: Side note, as this isn't actually part of your question, but I recommend removing the regular expression. Email address regex validation is far too complex, and you're likely to not be able to account for every possibility. If the user puts in an invalid email, that's their problem not yours. See this blog post for more in-depth discussion: https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your posted code, `if (isValidEmail(UserEmailTextFiled.text!)) {...` means that the *invalid* email alert will be displayed if the email is *valid*. You just need to reverse the result with a `!` `if (!isValidEmail(UserEmailTextFiled.text!)) {`

Answer (score 1):

```
public func isValidEmailAddress() -> Bool {
    let emailRegex = "^[\\w!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(?:\\.[\\w!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$"
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluate(with: self)
}
```

This is Swift 3.0 Func with regex.
just copy/paste in your helper or extensions file, and use it.

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3.0**

```
extension  String {

    func nsstring () -> NSString {
        return (self as NSString)
    }

    func isValidEmailAddress () -> Bool
    {

        var returnValue = true
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z.-_]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}"
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: emailRegEx)

            let results = regex.matches(in: self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.characters.count))
            if results.count == 0
            {
                returnValue = false
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            returnValue = false
        }
        return  returnValue
    }    
}
```

**In ViewController**

```
let isValidEmail = yourtextField?.text?.isValidEmailAddress()
if isValidEmail!
{ 
 //Code Here
}
else
{
 //Error Code Here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Email Validation in swift 3.0**

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailid: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var MsgAlrtEmailId: UILabel!

@IBAction func Register(_ sender: Any)
    {
        //email

        let providedEmailAddress = emailid.text

        let isEmailAddressValid = isValidEmailAddress(emailAddressString: providedEmailAddress!)

        if isEmailAddressValid
        {
            print("Email address is valid")
            MsgAlrtEmailId.text = "Email Address is valid"
            MsgAlrtEmailId.sizeToFit()
            MsgAlrtEmailId.textColor = UIColor.blue

        } else {
            print("Email address is not valid")
            MsgAlrtEmailId.text = "Email Address Not valid"
            MsgAlrtEmailId.sizeToFit()
           MsgAlrtEmailId.textColor = UIColor.red
        }

  //email rule validation
        func isValidEmailAddress(emailAddressString: String) -> Bool {

            var returnValue = true
            let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z.-_]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}"

            do {
                let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: emailRegEx)
                let nsString = emailAddressString as NSString
                let results = regex.matches(in: emailAddressString, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))

                if results.count == 0
                {
                    returnValue = false
                }

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                returnValue = false
            }

            return  returnValue
        }
```